# Laravel erro ao extrair dados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

O migrate não dá nenhum erro e também consigo popular a tabela normalmente com o seed. Mas quando eu tento extrair os dados do meu banco, não funciona.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $todos = Todo::all();

        return view('todos')->with('todos', $todos);
    }
}
```

O erro que eu recebo:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `todos`)"

Meu arquivo .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jvqNxaeClqTx0iU7pV9/oBo7Ca66CR8hAoga/Y236Qs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new-project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Já tentei usar:

```
C:\Users\Antony\Desktop\todos\blog>php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
```

Mas continuou a mesma coisa. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Além do config clear foi preciso usar:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

No homestead, a senha padrão do banco de dados é "secret".

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new-project
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Mais informações:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#connecting-to-databases